# Remove a part from string (maybe with regular expression)

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like this

```
string strAttachment ="3469¥cosmeticsview.png,3470¥SQL.txt";
```

Now I want only `"cosmeticsview.png,SQL.txt"` the file names from the string. The point is I want to find file names only so there isn't any digit in start and the "¥".

Foe now what I am doing is first I am doing split on "," then I am doing split on "¥" and after that I am getting the file name. Is there any way to do it with regular expressions.

Comment: It sure won't be any faster with regular expressions ;)

Comment: Why do you think it can be done faster? Are you having any performance issues? Did you search the web for your question?

Comment: No.. the I don't have any performance issue here. What I want is a generic solution for this.. and I think the regex will make the thing much lesser lines then split it twice ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `\d+¥` pattern:

```
string strAttachment = "3469¥cosmeticsview.png,3470¥SQL.txt";
var result = Regex.Replace(strAttachment, @"\d+¥", "");
```

But I don't think regex will be faster than usage of substring:

```
strAttachment.Split(',').Select(s => s.Substring(s.IndexOf('¥') + 1));
```

Comment: is there any faster way to do this?

Comment: performance won't be an issue no matter how big the string is..Except if your regex contain `.*` which could cause a lot of backtracking

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way

```
Regex.Split(input,@",?\d+¥")
```

Comment: Good option also - I always forget about Split method of Regex

Answer (score 0):

You can use Subsrting(startindex, length) using the index of ¥ as start, calculate length from total length and index of ",".

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx