# How to use $ symbol in Regex.Replace method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a string like following:

```
string strAttachment = "3469$cosmeticsview@.png,3470SQL.txt";
```

i want this:

```
cosmeticsview.png,SQL.txt
```

i try this:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(strAttachment, @"\d+@+$", "");
Response.Write(result);
```

but not work.

i think causes this problem is $ symbol.

***Edit***

I want remove digits also

Comment: You didn't ask the similar question around 30 minutes ago? Yeap you did http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19656833/remove-a-part-from-string-may-be-with-regular-expression

Comment: yes but $ symbol not worked

Comment: @SonerGönül that was about JPY, now its USD :)

Comment: Here's what I'm not understanding. You're looking for `1 or more digits` and then `1 or more @`, and then the end of the line. This Regex is so far from what you want, I just don't get it. I really don't.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky , do you know?

Comment: @SamieyMehdi yep, I know. Jonesy gave you correct answer (I think you should accept it). I provided some explanations and alternative solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems here - first is escaping of special regex symbols (end of line in your case). And second one is wrong pattern - your current solution tries to match `@` right after digits:

```
   one or more @ character
       |
       | end of line
       | |
    \d+@+$
     |
one or more digit
```

That will be matched by `hello1234@` which, of course, not your case. You want to remove either digits with dollar sign, or @ character. Here is correct pattern:

```
  one optional $ character
        |
        | OR
        | |
    \d+\$?|@
     |     |
     |   @ character
     |
one or more digit
```

Here is code:

```
string strAttachment = "3469$cosmeticsview@.png,3470SQL.txt";  
var result = Regex.Replace(strAttachment, @"\d+\$?|@", "");
```

Alternatively, if you just want to remove any digits, dollars and @ from your string:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(strAttachment, @"[\d\$@]+", "");
```

Comment: @SamieyMehdi `3470SQL.txt` do not have dollar sign. Any digit should be removed?

Answer (score 1):

try escaping it like `\$`

it's reserved in Regex to indicate the end of a line

Also, the `@+` isn't needed - that's not how regex works.  To get your desired result you want:

`\d+\$`

then use a Replace for the `@`:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(strAttachment, @"\d+$", "").Replace("@","");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're complicating this by trying to make a single pass. First get the part of the string you want (e.g. `cosmeticsview@.png,3470SQL.txt`):

```
var match = Regex.Match(strAttachment, @"\$(.*)");
if (!match.Success) { return; }
```

then strip the characters you don't want. Define a list like this somewhere:

```
List<char> invalidChars = new List<char> { '@' };
```

In my example I only added the `@`.

Now just remove those characters:

```
var val = string.Join("",
    match.Groups[1].Value
        .Where(c => !invalidChars.Contains(c))
);
```

Here is a [Regex 101](http://regex101.com/r/rO9uL0) to prove the Regex I provided.